# On each of them were

Tags: idiomatic-language

> On each of the seats were men from the drug gang.
>
> On each of the seats was a man from the drug gang.

Are these two equivalent? The first one doesn't sound grammatical, because it implies there were a lot of men sitting on one seat. How can I change the first sentence to mean on each seat there was a man from the drug gang and all of the seats were occupied by a man from the drug gang?

Comment: *On each **seat** was a man from the drug gang.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent in intended meaning and in everyday speech either one would probably pass without comment or concern.
But, as you say, a strict reading would give two different meanings, and if you mean to say that each seat held only one man only the second sentence would be correct.
This is because we are talking about **each seat** (singular), so we talk about **a man** (singular), even though there are multiple "each seat"s, if that makes sense.

To rephrase:

> Each seat held a man
> On each seat was a man
> There was a man in each seat
> A man was in each seat
> The seats were filled with men

That last does not necessarily mean *all* the seats had a man in them; you could make it so:

> All the seats were filled with men

Note that because we are talking about the seat**s** plural, we say **men** plural; this brings us back to the grammatical ambiguity as to whether some given single seat is occupied by *multiple* men.
But it is not likely to be interpreted that way.